# How to count the number of records with the same value in MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a collection of such data:

```
{ "_id" : "uCL87yuJ6s4YEbbNQ", "mrkPoradaData" : "09/21/2015 11:17 AM", "mrkPoradaHasloPrzedmiotowe" : "ubezpieczeniowa", "mrkPoradaRodzajPorady" : "ustna", "mrkPoradaSposobUdzieleniaPorady" : "internet", "mrkPoradaLp" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "EioktQ35byK8XPwbT", "mrkPoradaData" : "09/21/2015 11:19 AM", "mrkPoradaHasloPrzedmiotowe" : "finansowa (inne niż ubezpieczeniowa)", "mrkPoradaRodzajPorady" : "sporządzenie pisma", "mrkPoradaSposobUdzieleniaPorady" : "osobicie", "mrkPoradaLp" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "X6KvLcspEQKtJrFtu", "mrkPoradaData" : "09/21/2015 11:27 AM", "mrkPoradaHasloPrzedmiotowe" : "remontowo-budowlana", "mrkPoradaRodzajPorady" : "wzór pisma", "mrkPoradaSposobUdzieleniaPorady" : "telefonicznie", "mrkPoradaLp" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "TkAg8shdgQsoJuefe", "mrkPoradaData" : "09/21/2015 11:43 AM", "mrkPoradaHasloPrzedmiotowe" : "pocztowa", "mrkPoradaRodzajPorady" : "interwencja - wyjaśnienie telefoniczne", "mrkPoradaSposobUdzieleniaPorady" : "osobicie", "mrkPoradaLp" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "njFXYznRPpokJQviG", "mrkPoradaData" : "09/21/2015 11:43 AM", "mrkPoradaHasloPrzedmiotowe" : "wyposażenie wnętrz", "mrkPoradaRodzajPorady" : "ustna", "mrkPoradaSposobUdzieleniaPorady" : "internet", "mrkPoradaLp" : 5 }
```

How to count the number of records in the collection of data that the key `"mrkPoradaSposobUdzieleniaPorady"` has the following value `"internet"`?

Comment: This is an extremely basic question that could be answered by reading the simplest parts of the doc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`db.collection.count()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.count/), for example:

```
var result = Data.find({"mrkPoradaSposobUdzieleniaPorady": "internet"}).count();
```

Or if you need the documents anyway, you could fetch them and get the array's length via [`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

```
var documents = Data.find({"mrkPoradaSposobUdzieleniaPorady": "internet"}).fetch();
var result = documents.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Meteor collection object?..

```
// assuming Porada is the collection..
var internet = Porada.find({"mrkPoradaSposobUdzieleniaPorady": "internet"});
// internet.count() contains the count.
```